# MDX newbie: How do I filter/except based on an intermediate level which is not unique

Tags: mdx

I have a dimension ItemSales with a hierarchy of levels like Site->ItemType->Item

ItemType is not unique. Sites can sell the same ItemType.
I want to exclude a certain type from the totals (such as Unknown)

This must be easy but I'm stuck. It seems like Except would work but as far I can work out, except requires me to enumerate every site

Except([ItemSales].[Sites].[ItemType].Members],{[ItemSales].[site1].[unknown],[ItemSales].[site2].[Unknown]})

this also doesn't help if I just want to aggregate at Sites level.

The examples I see for filter focus on numerical filters for measures. Can you filter on the name of a member or whatever we call the key value it gets from the column?

Sorry for asking such an easy question but I'm not getting any less confused the more I read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way to address your problem, but you can do something with the [Filter](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.html)() function using the .name of the members to keep all [ItemType] that are not 'Unknown' :

```
Filter( 
  [ItemSales].[Sites].[ItemType].Members, 
  [ItemSales].[Sites].currentMember.name <> 'Unknown' 
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I want. Now I just have to understand how it works.